# Running redmine on apache2 with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have installed redmine and its working properly on webrick. I am trying to run it on apache and have installed passenger and its apache module. When I try to run redmine on apache i get this error messge

**Ruby on Rails application could not be started**

**Error message:
    Could not find RubyGem rack (~> 1.1.0)**

I have rack 1.1.0 installed and the ruby 1.8.7

gem list shows this

actionmailer (2.3.14)
actionpack (2.3.14)
activerecord (2.3.14)
activeresource (2.3.14)
activesupport (2.3.14)
bundler (1.0.21)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
json (1.6.5)
mysql (2.8.1)
passenger (3.0.11)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.3.14)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These gems might be installed for a specific user and the Apache user might not have access to that. In that case, be sure to install them globally, by doing a `sudo gem install....`.

It is also possible that you are using tools like rvm and have installed the gems into a specific gemset. See the [rvm documentation](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/) if this is the case.